# Multivariate hierarchical clustering methods in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am looking for R packages for hierarchical clustering (or other clustering methods) that can handle mixed data types. I have a data set with continuous and ordinal variables.
Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am using FactoMineR. This can handle mixed data easily and is well documented.

Damien